# Matrix in Python give wrong results using Numpy Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a complete beginner with NumPy and I am trying to generate the following matrix pattern. Below is my code. What I am not figuring out is that what am I doing wrong to get this result. Thanks in advance for any help.

```py
    import numpy as np 

    def matrix(n): 
        final = []
        for i in range(n): 
            final.append(list(np.tile([0,1],int(n/2))) if i%2==0 else list(np.tile([1,0],int(n/2)))) 
        print(np.array(final)) 


    size = 8
    matrix(size)
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear, what you want to do.

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma Dear, if the user enters 9 then the above image like pattern will be generated like 9 rows and 9 columns and the same with the case with other numbers like entering 8 will generate 8 rows and 8 cols like the pattern above shown.

Comment: What's the pattern? [[1]], pad[0]*1, pad[1]*2, pad[0]*3 and so on or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using numpy you should avoid working with arrays and for loops for matrix creating and editing because for large matrices it would be very slow.

Try to examine this code:

```
import math
import numpy as np


def zero_borders(mat: np.ndarray) -> None:
    """Makes the borders of the array zero."""
    mat[:, 0] = 0  # left border
    mat[:, -1] = 0  # right border
    mat[0, :] = 0  # upper border
    mat[-1, :] = 0  # bottom border


def zero_center_square(mat: np.ndarray) -> None:
    """Makes small square of zeros in the center of the array."""
    size = mat.shape[0]
    i_low = size//2 - 1
    i_high = math.ceil(size/2)
    mat[i_low, i_low:i_high + 1] = 0  # upper edge of the square
    mat[i_high, i_low:i_high + 1] = 0  # upper edge of the square
    mat[i_low:i_high + 1, i_low] = 0  # left edge of the square
    mat[i_low:i_high + 1, i_high] = 0  # right edge of the square


def matrix(n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    """Creates a square matrix with special pattern."""
    mat = np.ones((n, n))
    zero_borders(mat)
    zero_center_square(mat)
    return mat


def main():
    print("Even size:")
    print(matrix(8))
    print("")
    print("Odd size:")
    print(matrix(9))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output:

```
Even size:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]

Odd size:
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy ix_() like this:

```
>>> x = np.zeros((9,9), dtype=int)
>>> p1 = np.ix_([1,2,6,7],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
>>> x[p]=1
>>> p2 = np.ix_([3,4,5],[1,2,6,7])
>>> x[p2]=1
>>> x
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned any particular pattern for `lxl` length of matrix, so I will write just code about how to generate the matrix in given image.

You can use `NumPy` (particularly `numpy.pad()`) to create that matrix easily as:

```
import numpy as np

# Create required matrix
matrix = np.pad(np.pad(np.pad(np.array([[1]]), (1, 1)), (2, 2), constant_values = 1), (1, 1))

# If you want that as list instead of NumPy array
list_matrix = list(list(i) for i in matrix)
```